# Unable to change the path used for PIP in python

Tags: python, pip

I have installed a new version of python (3.10) and before that I uninstalled 3.8 version. Now when I'm trying to use pip, it's showing the old location of pip and the commands aren't getting executed. How do I change the location it points to?
[Screen Shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QDg3.png)

Comment: maybe try reinstalling pip to the correct location

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can not use Python 3.8's pip with Python 3.10. Your Python setup seems to be "messed up", probably something went wrong when uninstalling Python 3.8. If needed you might consider reinstalling Python 3.8 again then uninstalling it in the hope that this time the uninstall goes right. -- Also note that in principle you can keep both Python 3.8 and Python 3.10 installed at the same time on the same machine. -- And in general use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip ...` commands: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/